# incompatible fortran and C when compiling mpich

Tags: gcc, fortran, mpich

I am configuring mpich 3.4.3 by using Intel fortran(not gfortran) and gcc, and my system is ubuntu18.04. I compiled by:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mpich --with-device=ch3
```

When I use gfortran and gcc (the default mode) to comfigure, all works well, but my model needs intel fortran but not gfortran, so I added before configuring like:

```
export FC=ifort
export F90=ifort
unset F90
unset F90FLAGS
```

Then I reconfigured, however, here appears the error:

```
error: **** Incompatible Fortran and C object file types!
F77 object file type produced by"ifort -m64" is:: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64,version 1(GNU/LINUX), not stripped.
C object file type produced by"gcc -O2" is:: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64,version 1(SYSV), not stripped.
```

I searched and found most of the cases are about problem of mac-OS 32-bit and 64-bit, but my system is not mac OS, I have no idea which vetsion I should change. Also, I need both ifort and gcc, so I can't disable any of them. Thank you so much if someone replies!

Comment: Welcome. How do you configure MPICH? What exact commands are you running? See [ask] and [mcve]. We need to know what you are actually doing.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have already edited the question and put my commands here. I export FC as ifort before configure.